# json_decode - issues with api

Tags: php, api

I am trying to find the game someone is playing on twitch by using the api. I have setup the json_decode and it shows all of the content from the api. However whenever I try to `print_r` the game I get an error.

The error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$game in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\Portfolio -- Website\twitchstreaminfo\streaminfo.php on line31
```

PHP code:

```
$streamer = $_POST['username'];
$apiurl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" . $streamer;
$apicontent = file_get_contents($apiurl);
$streamerinfo = json_decode($apicontent);
print_r($streamerinfo->game);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just doing the following first and verify the result:

```
print_r( $streamerinfo );
```

From what I can see with the API, the following should work:

```
print_r( $streamerinfo->stream->game );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is saying that the propery of "$game" does not exist on the object "$streamerinfo". As suggested above, try priting the "$streamerinfo" to varify that it is valid. Another thing you can do to prevent this is to add the following :

```
if (isset($streamerinfo->game) {
     print_r($streamerinfo->game);
}
```

That code will prevent this error, but not fix the problem. I suggest this as a final solution to help you solve the problem

```
   if (isset($streamerinfo->game) {
     print_r($streamerinfo->game);
   } else {
     print_r($streamerinfo);
   }
```

This will keep your code from breaking in the way that it is now. But, it will also print "$streamerinfo" if it fails. This way you can see why it failed.